# json_decode keeps returning null

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to convert some JSON to an associate array in PHP. For some reason, the result of `json_decode()` is always NULL.

I guess my JSON must be malformed, but I don't know *why*. What's malformed about it?

```
<?php

$json = '{ markers:{ marker:[ { lat:50.30644, lng:18.03125, title:"Some name with accented characters ÅÄÖ", zoom:13, center:"false", street:"Dalahästvägen 56", zip:{ }, city:"117 58 MALMÖ", country:"SE", phone:"070-880 60 14", www:"domain.se/" }, { lat:59.5306, lng:18.08521, title:"ACME INC", zoom:13, center:"false", street:"ELFSBORGSVÄGEN 9", zip:{ }, city:"186 41 SIGTUNA", country:"SE", phone:"08-511 700 70", www:"acmegiantslingshots.se" }]}}' ;

$arr = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($arr);
```

Is it because some of the object properties have no value?

Comment: your json is not valid check here http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All strings and keys must be quoted using `"` (double quotes) to comply with the JSON spec.

http://jsonlint.com is usually a good tool when you have something that breaks your JSON parser.